# AWS CodeBuild Intermittent Failure on rake assetts:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, aws-codebuild

When I try to use this dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6-alpine

RUN apk --update --no-cache add build-base linux-headers nodejs yarn mariadb-dev tzdata
RUN apk --update --no-cache add --virtual build-dependencies make g++

RUN mkdir -p /app/disease-trakker
RUN mkdir -p /app/disease-trakker/app/assets/stylesheets

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/disease-trakker/
WORKDIR /app/disease-trakker
RUN gem install bundler && bundle config set without 'development test' && bundle config set deployment 'true'
RUN bundle install --jobs $(nproc)
RUN yarn install
RUN apk del build-dependencies && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm -rf /usr/local/bundle/cache/*.gem && find /usr/local/bundle/gems/ -name "*.c" -delete

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S app && adduser -u 1000 -S app -G app
COPY . /app/disease-trakker

RUN yarn global add node-gyp
RUN yarn install --no-optional
RUN yarn cache clean
RUN RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=precompile_only bundle exec rake assets:precompile
RUN rm -rf node_modules tmp/ vendor/assets lib/assets test/
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV RAILS_ENV production

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chown app:app /usr/local/bundle/config
RUN chown -R app:app /app/disease-trakker
USER app

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

To build an image on AWS CodeBuild, it fails about 4 out of every 5 runs on the step:

```
RUN RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=precompile_only bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

With the message:

```
Compilation failed:
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:677:19)
    at ChildProcessWorker.send (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:291:17)
    at WorkerPool.send (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:32:34)
    at Farm._process (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/Farm.js:129:10)
    at Farm._enqueue (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/Farm.js:152:10)
    at Farm._push (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/Farm.js:159:12)
    at /app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/Farm.js:90:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Farm.doWork (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/Farm.js:56:12)
    at JestWorker._callFunctionWithArgs (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:143:23)
    at TaskRunner.runTask (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:41:26)
    at enqueue (/app/disease-trakker/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:89:35)
    at /app/disease-trakker/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:113:86
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at internal/child_process.js:810:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}

The command '/bin/sh -c RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=precompile_only bundle exec rake assets:precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It also fails on my local machine, but less often.

Why is my build failing? What steps can I take to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: "It also fails on my local machine, but less often." - So it only fails sometimes? I would check and see if you have any syntax errors in your JS files

Comment: It fails more often on AWS, but it sometimes succeeds on either my local or on CodeBuild. Wouldn't a syntax error always cause a failure?

Comment: Yes it would, was there a point were this wasnt happening. It might be easier to try to pinpoint when it started and see what changes could have caused the issue

Comment: Nope. The build has always failed at least half the time on this particular step.